# Diagnóstico em código que recupera JPG's de arquivo

Tags: c

Em um exercício de curso tenho que escrever um programa que recupera imagens JPG de um arquivo. O código abaixo não esta pronto, mas ele deveria encontrar as assinaturas de JPG (0xffd8ffe0 ou 0xffd8ffe1) dentro do arquivo pulando de 512 em 512 bytes (FAT) e imprimir um texto. Dúvida:

- O código não funciona, não consigo diagnosticar, quais são os
  problemas?

Arquivo: https://github.com/kaarejoergensen/pset5/blob/master/jpg/card.raw

Código:

```
/**********************************
 * recover.c
 * CC50 Pset5
 * Recupera imagens JPG. Matheus.
 *********************************/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    // Boas Vindas
    printf("\033[1;30;47mPOWERED BY RAMALHOLIVEIRA\033[0m\nIniciando operação.\n");

    // Abrir Arquivo
    FILE *fpr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (fpr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\033[31mErro ao abrir o arquivo.\033[0m\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Variáveis
    uint32_t cursor = 0;
    uint32_t assinatura = 0x00;
    FILE *saida = fopen("saida", "w");
    int n = 1;

    // Se 'fread' retornar 0 o loop acaba
    do
    {
        // Lê 4 bytes e armazena em 'assinatura'
        cursor = fread(&assinatura, 4, 1, fpr);
        fwrite(&assinatura, 4, 1, saida);
        if (assinatura == 0xffd8ffe0 || assinatura == 0xffd8ffe1)
        {
            printf("%d Encontrado!\n", n);
            ++n;
        }
        fseek(fpr, 512, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    while (cursor != 0);

    // Isso é tudo, pessoal :)
    fclose(fpr);
    fclose(saida);
    printf("Isso é tudo, pessoal.\n");
    return 0;
}
```